# Java Sql Builder for DDL operatons with safe from sqlinjections

Tags: java, postgresql, ddl, builder

In my service, I get a table name and a set of columns (with names and types) from api. I want to generate a sql string with which you can create a table in a database (postgres) with the specified name and columns (dynamically, the number of columns can be different). At the same time that it would be safe from sql injections and other bad things. Is there any solution for this DDL operations for Java (without ORM, only plain jdbc)?

Comment: Do you try Jooq or QueryDsl?

Comment: jooq is for ORM,  no?. what about QueryDsl - does it know how to create queries for ddl? like "create schema .." or "create table name (column type, ...etc)"?

Comment: What's problem with ORM? Jooq is just library for transparent generating sql with type safety